# Comment reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I understand why you require rep to comment on answers, but you must realize this discourages experienced engineers who have yet to create an account from participating on the site.

Comment: And you must also realize how annoying it is when you got a bunch of notification which are spam.

Answer (score 6):

### It's really not all that hard to get the 50 rep needed to comment anywhere.

Although I agree with your idea about experienced engineers not being able to comment, you must also understand that there are *plenty* of low-rep users that are ***not*** experienced engineers. Moderators like this policy because it keeps the little number in thier toolbar low - spammers are (often) in low-rep accounts.

Also, if experienced engineers really want to comment *that bad*, they can probably answer a question or two and get the needed reputation rather quickly. **Spammers aren't known for their expertise in multithreaded iOS applications, and hence the rep barrier.**

Comment: It's more than 10 or 20.  (If you put it in bold at the top of your answer, should probably be correct.)

Comment: @djechlin Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out - it's what I get for not doing my research in the FAQ

Comment: @ErwaySoftware: What about a person like me having 18k+ Even I can spam? i will post some spam answers. i will get few downvotes and then I can delete it. I would say in review sections, there are cap of 20 to 40 for all categories, it can be incresed...so that all spams/flags can be checked quickly. No queues to get approved/rejected etc

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Spam-flags will earn you -100 rep, highly discouraging *anyone* to post spam posts. I'd rather have the occasional falling-down 10k+ user spamming (highly unlikely) than 100 000 unregistered accounts overflowing the site with gucci bags.

Comment: @J.Steen: Oh is it. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: All true. Worth to add that if "experienced engineer" got something to fix or improve in a post he can always suggest an edit. This can be done by any visitor, not requiring to even have account. The edit might be rejected if too radical, but some of those are actually valid.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that there's a "We trust you on other sites in the network" global privilege that gives you 100 rep (that's how I was able to post this comment fyi :) ).   I don't remember the exact amount of reputation required to get this, but I think it's somewhere around 1500 rep.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are generally not the kind of participation we want to promote or attract.  We want experienced engineers to provide *answers,* not jump in on discussions.  In fact we want discussion kept to a minimum and answers to be the focus.