# Can't undo my vote after question was edited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, edits, grace-period

This one:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176449/183887

1. I downvoted and commented.
2. Question was edited.
3. "You last voted on this question 8 minutes ago..."

I think the issue here was the "I can change my vote as much as I want" window ended after the edit that made me want to change my vote.

Comment: Actually thats not a bug because the post has been edit in its 5 minute of grace period and thus its like there were "no edit". See the question "Dont lock vote on the meta" (cant link right now Im on my phone)

Comment: @HugoDozois you're welcome :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites

Comment: @HugoDozois One, it's not a duplicate.  I actually have a (far-downvoted) answer on that question saying I think votes should be locked on meta like on all other sites.

Comment: @HugoDozois Two, it's a bug.  An edit in the "edit" grace period should count toward a vote being able to be changed.  It used to be a bad answer.  It was edited.  Now it's a good answer.  Why can't I change my vote?  Should I have left a note in my comment saying "wait until your grace period is over in case I'm AFK?"

Comment: My bad - the duplicate is correct.

Comment: @djechlin by the way I never said it was duplicate, I just linked the topic because it was related

Comment: @HugoDozois yeah, it was my mistake - the question was closed as a different dupe and I conflated.